# Throw and Catch or Return inside Compile

Tags: compile, return-value

Consider this code:

```
fun = Compile[{}, 
  Catch[Do[
    rn = RandomChoice[{0.8, 0.1, 0.1} -> {1, 2, 3}];
    If[rn > 1, Throw[j]]
    , {j, 1, 10}]]
  , CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

At each iteration a number randomly is chosen and if it is greater than 1, then the code must return the number of the iteration in which the condition is satisfied.

If I don't compile to `C`, then everything is fine, but if I compile to `C` then I get this error message:

> > CompiledFunction::cflist: Nontensor object generated; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>

In the documents says it happen when someone tries to add two unequal-in-length lists. I can't see how this cause the problem as I don't add any two lists in the code.

Using `Return` intead of `Throw` makes a similar error.

### Edit

I think this question might be relevant to this [one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73786/throw-and-catch-return-wrong-result-inside-compile). I think because sometimes the `Throw` returns `Null` there is error.

Comment: Is it possible to define the output so that it can returns `Null` too?

Comment: Suppose I give the result of the `If` statement to another variable like `x`. Is it possible to check whether x is `Null` and if so set it equal to 0?
Like `If[x==Null,x=0]`

Answer (score 2):

If you localize `rn`, then it works.

```
fun = Compile[{}, 
  Module[{rn}, 
   Catch[Do[rn = RandomChoice[{0.8, 0.1, 0.1} -> {1, 2, 3}];
     If[rn > 1, Throw[j]], {j, 1, 10}]]], CompilationTarget -> "C"]


Table[fun[], {10}]
(*  {1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 10, 2, 11, 2, 7}  *)
```

Comment: why does this ever return 11?

Comment: @george2079 In the WVM code, `j` is `11` when the loop ends and the instruction right after the loop assigns the value `j` to the return register.  See yashar's other post, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73786/throw-and-catch-return-wrong-result-inside-compile, for a discussion.  (I don't think it ought to return `11`, of course. It's arguably a bug in the compiler.)

Comment: Is there a way to see the generated c code?  in any case putting ';0' , or whatever value you want, after the `Do` inside `Catch` should let you control the default return value..

Comment: @george2079 I made such a comment to the OP's q., which I since deleted because it contained an incorrect suggestion of what was going wrong.  yashar didn't seem interested.  The C code is stored in a directory.  Compile with ``Compiler`$CCompilerOptions = {"CleanIntermediate" -> False}`` and inspect `fun // InputForm`; the directory will be in a subdirectory of the directory containing the .dylib file (at least on Mac OSX, Mma V10.0.2).